# Code for items in gallery to filter using dropdown on Power apps

Tags: powerquery

I'm trying to filter a gallery by saying that when the dropdown can be edited and an option is selected, it would filter according to that in a particular category, otherwise it would just filter by category.

My code for items is,

```
If(ddStatus.DisplayMode.Edit, 
    Filter('List', Category.Value = "1" && 'Status'.Value = ddStatus.Selected.Value), 
    Filter('List', Category.Value = "1")
)
```

But with this code, it just filters by category and not by status when an option from the dropdown is selected. Is there some error here?